# how can I change the default language loaded in a project using pinax (django)

Tags: django, pinax

I'm working with the basic_project of Pinax and I need to change the default language of the application from english to french or to spanish

I'd tried changing the variable

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es',

but it remains in english, even the admin, so Im guessing this change does not have any effect at all.

where can I continue looking for more information about this?

In the past, in a Django application (not using pinax) I have changed that parameter  and it did work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems only the [social_project](http://github.com/pinax/pinax/tree/969264eec8d9a85dd59585070c6b3dec865fc464/pinax/projects/social_project/locale) has localization files available. Try copying the "es" directory to basic_project/locale and see if that works!